# Is it possible to restore accordion panels with shiny bookmarking?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I have this app where bookmarking shiny works great, except it only restores the last accordion panel after a page refresh. If I regenerate the same panel, then I can see that the text input is restored. But it requires the user to regenerate the panels. Is it possible to restore the accordion panels with bookmarking?

#### Example app

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 5),
    titlePanel("Dynamic Tabs with Bookmarking"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("tab_name", "Tab Name"),
        actionButton("add_tab", "Add Tab")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        accordion(
          id = "tabs"
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store tab names
  tabs <- reactiveVal(character(0))

  # Function to add a new tab
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    new_tab_name <- isolate(input$tab_name)
    if (!is.null(new_tab_name) && new_tab_name != "") {
      accordion_panel_insert(id = "tabs",
                panel = accordion_panel(title = new_tab_name, value = new_tab_name,
                                        textInput(paste0(new_tab_name, "_my"), label="Enter:"))
      )
      # Update reactive value with new tab name
      tabs(c(tabs(), new_tab_name))
    }
  })


  # Update bookmark state
  observe({

    session$doBookmark()
  })

  # Update URL
  onBookmarked(updateQueryString)
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `onBookmark` and `onRestore`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 5),
    titlePanel("Dynamic Tabs with Bookmarking"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("tab_name", "Tab Name"),
        actionButton("add_tab", "Add Tab")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        accordion(
          id = "tabs"
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive value to store tab names
  tabs <- reactiveVal(character(0))
  
  # Function to add a new tab
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    new_tab_name <- isolate(input$tab_name)
    if (!is.null(new_tab_name) && new_tab_name != "") {
      accordion_panel_insert(id = "tabs",
                             panel = accordion_panel(title = new_tab_name, value = new_tab_name,
                                                     textInput(paste0(new_tab_name, "_my"), label="Enter:"))
      )
      # Update reactive value with new tab name
      tabs(c(tabs(), new_tab_name))
    }
  })
  
  
  # Update bookmark state
  observe({
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  
  onBookmark(function(state) {
    state$values$Tabs <- tabs()
  })
  
  onRestore(function(state) {
    for(tab_name in head(state$values$Tabs, -1)) {
      accordion_panel_insert(
        id = "tabs",
        panel = accordion_panel(
          title = tab_name, value = tab_name,
          textInput(paste0(tab_name, "_my"), label="Enter:")
        )
      )
    }
  })
  
  # Update URL
  onBookmarked(updateQueryString)
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```