# Restoring accordion panels in a modularized shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

My previous, related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78043187/2829961) (answered).

#### Goal

Users dynamically generate a number of accordion panels in a shiny app. The app must bookmark them and restore them upon a page refresh (e.g., if a disconnection happens).

#### Problem

In a simple app, all the accordion panels and their values are successfully restored, as shown in the related answer linked above. But in the modularized app, only the last panel is restored. I am not sure what I am missing in the code.

#### Code

```
mod_form_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("event_form"))
  )
}

mod_form_server <- function(id, event_name, Day) {


  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      # Event name as a function of day
      sim_event <- reactive(paste0("event_", gsub("\\s", "", event_name), "_", Day))

      output$event_form <- renderUI({

        tagList(
          textAreaInput(
            inputId = ns(paste0(sim_event(), "_eventStart")),
            label = "Event Start",
            placeholder = "Event started at ..."
          )
        )

      })

    }
  )
}



mod_all_events_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("add"), "New Event"),
    br(),
    accordion(
      id = ns("accord_all_events")
    )
  )
}

mod_all_events_server <- function(id, Day) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      # When the 'New Event' button is clicked, a modal pops up asking for event name.
      observeEvent(input$add, {

          showModal(
            modalDialog(
              tagList(
                textInput(
                  inputId = ns("event_name"),
                  label = "Event name:",
                  value = ""
                ),
                ## this button will take to the main modal
                actionButton(ns("create_event"), "Submit")
              ),
              title = "New Event",
              footer = modalButton("Dismiss")
            )
          )

      })

      # Reactive value to store tab names
      events <- reactiveVal(character(0))

      # When Submit button is clicked, a new form is created in an accordion panel
      observeEvent(input$create_event, {

        req(input$event_name)

        removeModal()

        new_event_name <- isolate(input$event_name)

        form_id <- paste0(gsub("\\s", "", new_event_name), "_form")

        accordion_panel_insert(id = "accord_all_events",
                               panel = accordion_panel(title = new_event_name,
                                                       mod_form_ui(ns(form_id))))

        accordion_panel_close(id = "accord_all_events", values = TRUE)


        mod_form_server(form_id, new_event_name, Day)

        # Update reactive value with new tab name
        events(c(events(), list(name = new_event_name, id = form_id)))

      })



      onBookmark(function(state) {
        state$values$Events <- events()
      })

      onRestore(function(state) {
        for(event in head(state$values$Events, -1)) {
          form_id <- event$id
          accordion_panel_insert(
            id = "accord_all_events",
            panel = accordion_panel(
              title = event$name,
              mod_form_ui(ns(form_id))
            )
          )

          mod_form_server(form_id, event$name, Day)
        }
      })

    }
  )
}


create_day_page <- function(x) {
  number <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x))
  navset_card_pill(
    id = paste0("pill_", number),
    nav_panel(
      title = "All Events",
      mod_all_events_ui(paste0("all_events_", number))
    )
  )
}



library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Main UI
ui <- function(request) {
  page_navbar(

  title = "CI",

  sidebar = sidebar(
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "day",
      label = HTML("Select Day: <span style='color:red'>*</span>"),
      choices = c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6", "Day7"),
      options = list(
        placeholder = 'Select day',
        onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
      )
    )
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.day !== ''",
    shiny::uiOutput("day_page")
  ),

  nav_item(
    uiOutput("sign_out_button")
  )
)
}

# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    ## Observe selected day input and then create UI for that day
  observe({
    ## Check if a day is selected
    if (!is.null(input$day) && input$day != "") {
      ## Render the day page
      output$day_page <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          h4(gsub("Day(\\d+)", "Day \\1", input$day)),
          create_day_page(input$day)
        )
      })


      ## All events server
      number <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", input$day))
      Day <- paste0("Day", number)
      mod_all_events_server(id = paste0("all_events_", number), input$day)
    }
  })

  observe({
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(updateQueryString)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That sounds highly complicated. First, the `onBookmark/onRestore` of the module are not found because you call this module in an observer. You can call this module for all possible days but not inside an observer, that solves this first problem. But then, when you restore the app, `input$add` and `input$create_event` are not `0`, and then the observers attached to these inputs are executed.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Could excluding those inputs from the bookmarks work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bookmarking; is it possible to exclude some inputs?

Comment: I'm also learning. The function `setBookmarkExclude` seems to exclude the chosen inputs from bookmarking: https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.0/setbookmarkexclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works :) I had to do numerous changes. Notably, don't call the module servers in an observer.

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

mod_form_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textAreaInput(
    inputId = ns("eventStart"),
    label = "Event Start",
    placeholder = "Event started at ..."
  )
}

mod_all_events_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("add"), "New Event"),
    br(),
    accordion(
      id = ns("accord_all_events")
    )
  )
}

mod_all_events_server <- function(id, Day) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      # When the 'New Event' button is clicked, a modal pops up asking for event name.
      observeEvent(input$add, {
        
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            tagList(
              textInput(
                inputId = ns("event_name"),
                label = "Event name:",
                value = ""
              ),
              ## this button will take to the main modal
              actionButton(ns("create_event"), "Submit")
            ),
            title = "New Event",
            footer = modalButton("Dismiss")
          )
        )
        
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
      
      # Reactive value to store tab names
      events <- reactiveVal()
      
      # When Submit button is clicked, a new form is created in an accordion panel
      observeEvent(input$create_event, {
        
        req(input$event_name)
        removeModal()
        new_event_name <- input$event_name
        form_id <- paste0(gsub("\\s", "", new_event_name), "_form")
        
        accordion_panel_insert(id = "accord_all_events",
                               panel = accordion_panel(title = new_event_name,
                                                       mod_form_ui(ns(form_id))))
        accordion_panel_close(id = "accord_all_events", values = TRUE)
        
        # Update reactive value with new tab name
        events(
          c(
            events(), 
            list(list(name = new_event_name, id = form_id))
          )
        )
        
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
      
      onBookmark(function(state) {
        state$values$Events <- isolate(events())
      })
      
      onRestore(function(state) {
        if(!is.null(state$values$Events)) {
          # note: the list is converted to a dataframe!
          for(i in seq_len(nrow(state$values$Events))) {
            event <- state$values$Events[i, , drop = FALSE]
            form_id <- event$id
            accordion_panel_insert(
              id = "accord_all_events",
              panel = accordion_panel(
                title = event$name,
                mod_form_ui(ns(form_id))
              ),
              session = session
            )
          }
        }
      })
      
      setBookmarkExclude(c("add", "create_event", "event_name", "accord_all_events"))
      
      # we return the reactive value in order to trigger session$doBookmark when it changes 
      return(events) 
    }
  )
}


create_day_page <- function(x) {
  number <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x))
  navset_card_pill(
    id = paste0("pill_", number),
    nav_panel(
      title = "All Events",
      mod_all_events_ui(paste0("all_events_", number))
    )
  )
}

# Main UI
ui <- function(request) {
  page_fillable(
    
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = "day",
          label = HTML("Select Day: <span style='color:red'>*</span>"),
          choices = c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3", "Day4", "Day5", "Day6", "Day7"),
          options = list(
            placeholder = 'Select day',
            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
          )
        )
      ),
      lapply(paste0("Day", 1:7), function(day) {
        number <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", day))
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = sprintf("input.day == '%s'", day),
          tags$div(
            h4(gsub("Day(\\d+)", "Day \\1", day)),
            navset_card_pill(
              id = paste0("pill_", number),
              nav_panel(
                title = "All Events",
                mod_all_events_ui(paste0("all_events_", number))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      })
      
      # nav_item(
      #   uiOutput("sign_out_button")
      # )
      
    )
  )
}

# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  events <- vector("list", length = 7)
  
  lapply(1:7, function(i) {
    day <- paste0("Day", i)
    events[[i]] <<- mod_all_events_server(id = paste0("all_events_", i), day)
  })  
  
  observe({
    lapply(events, function(x) x())
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  onBookmarked(updateQueryString)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this solution. Could you please elaborate on why putting module servers in observers was not a good idea? Was it because they were not triggered?

Comment: In your solution, `
mod_form_server` is omitted but it is needed. Including it throws errors in `onRestore`. It probably requires creating multiple `state$values` items for different arguments in `mod_form_server`. But all my attempts throw errors.

Comment: @umairdurrani Why is it needed?

Comment: @umairdurrani The problem is that you use the user input `event_name` in your `mod_form_server`, so you are obliged to call it from an observer and that is bad. Instead, you can do `mod_form_ui <- function(id, event_name, Day)`. No?

Comment: `mod_form_server` is needed because it is the server part of the form module. It contains several inputs and other stuff which is not included in the example code in the question, but even the example code contains 1 input that is needed server side. I understand your other comment about observers, thanks.

Comment: @umairdurrani Sorry I can't help without more information about this module. In the code I gave, `mod_form_ui` is not necessary: you can directly include the `textAreaInput` in `accordion_insert_panel`.